# WAMP Mysql database version change

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

Can someone help me out of this error?

I had old version of wamp, because of virus I have formatted my computer, although I have backed-up the "wamp\bin\MySQL\mysql5.5.24\data". Now, I have installed the new version of "WAMP". It comes with the new "mysal5.6.12\data", I have tried to copy "data" in that folder but it not works.

My entire database which I have backed-up, is not working so, please somebody help me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your current WAMP server.

Install your previous version of WAMP server.

Import your database from your data file.

Export your whole database as SQL.

Install new version of WAMP server.

Import your new SQL to new WAMP server.

Comment: i have install both the version.  now it's working by changing mysql version.

Comment: better if you save your db via SQL scripts, you will avoid these complications

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed up after some troubles.

You can reinstall all your data by copying over the contents from the old wamp server to the new one

Just check your new mysql version and into wamp/bin/your version/data backup that folder into /backups

Then copy over wamp/bin/your old version/data to the folder above wamp/bin/your version/data

This should load wamp server but with an orange icon

Go to the backups folder and copy the mysql, perfomance schema and test folders into the new

That should work out

If you have troubles let me know

Comment: Is your caps lock key stuck?